# Want a phrase/word to express the time follow and close now

Tags: phrase-requests

I want a phrase or word to express the time follow and close now, it would have the meaning that keeps the time continuous. for me, word "later" seems be too generic, "later on" seems to have certain period time after now: "follow on" looks also not a good idea.

For example: after reading this book (?) I start go to work.(after reading book I Immediately start go to work, there would have no interval between two things )

Comment: What is wrong with "immediately"? You yourself used that word to explain it to us; what prevents you from using it on other occasions?

Comment: immediately I don't think it is very good choice, I want stress the time. time 2 closes time 1, but immediately stress the things I did right the way.

Comment: Without some editing, it is difficult to guess what is being asked here.

Answer (score 3):

An unexpected possibility it may be but the answer is ***right***.

"... *right* after reading the book" has the meaning you are looking for. That would be simple and easy to understand; convey the meaning of "immediately after."

"I start for work **right** after reading the book." ('to go' may not be needed.)

Answer (score 2):

*[Directly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/directly?rdfrom=Directly)* ("immediately" and 
"soon; next; when it becomes convenient"),  is appropriate here, although wiktionary refers to the former usage as *dated* and the other as localized.  In some cases, preposition *[upon](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upon)* (in sense "at a prescribed point in time") or adverb *[when](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/when)* may serve:

> I started work directly upon finishing the book.
>   Upon finishing the book, I started work.
>   I started work when I finished the book.
>   I'll start work when I finish the book.

Answer (score 0):

*Then* indicates it's the next thing to happen:

> I read this book, then I went to work.

If you start it with the time preposition like that, you don't need any word:

> After I read this book, I went to work.

Worded less awkwardly:

> I went to work after I read this book.